# Is there any way where we can get the current page number in PDFView and use it in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, pdf, swiftui, pdfview, ios-pdfkit

I am making an app pdf reader using PDFKit but I am unable to get the current page number. I can get the total pages by `pdfView.document?.pageCount`. The alternative way we can use for this is to change the page by button and count it but I want the PDFView default feature **Changing the page by Swipe** by sitting the  `pdfView.usePageViewController(true)` but it does not give any method to get the current page number

**Code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "pdf")
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            PDFKitRepresentedView(data: try! Data(contentsOf: url!))
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
import PDFKit
import SwiftUI


struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    let data: Data
    func makeUIView(context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> UIViewType {
        // Create a `PDFView` and set its `PDFDocument`.
        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
        pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.maxScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        
        return pdfView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: UIViewType, context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
    }
}
```

**Update**

According to suggestion given by
**workingdog support Ukraine** below the coordinator class printing the result but when I use Binding to pass the currentPage to SwiftUI its not working the page number is not updating in UI and on swiping its repeating the first two pages only

**New Updated code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentPage = -1
    @State var totalPages :Int?
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "pdf")
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("\(currentPage)/")
                Text("\(totalPages ?? 0)")
            }
            if let url = url {
                PDFKitRepresentedView(data:try! Data(contentsOf: url),totalPages: $totalPages,currentPage: $currentPage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    let data: Data
    @Binding var totalPages:Int?
    @Binding var currentPage :Int
    let pdfView = PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
        pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.maxScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: UIViewType, context _: Context) {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            totalPages = pdfView.document?.pageCount
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self, cp: $currentPage)
    }
        
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PDFViewDelegate {
        var parent: PDFKitRepresentedView
        @Binding var currentPage :Int
        
        init(_ parent: PDFKitRepresentedView,cp:Binding<Int>) {
            self.parent = parent
            _currentPage = cp
            super.init()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pageChangeHandler(_:)), name: .PDFViewPageChanged, object: nil)
        }

        @objc func pageChangeHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
            
            if let thePage = parent.pdfView.currentPage,
                let ndx = parent.pdfView.document?.index(for: thePage),
               currentPage != ndx {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.currentPage = ndx
                }
                print("--------> currentPageIndex: \(ndx) ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview there is a `currentPage` that returns the current page. You could then use something like this to get the index of it:

```
if let thePage = pdfView.currentPage, let ndx = pdfView.document?.index(for: thePage) {
   print("--> currentPageIndex: \(ndx) ")
   // ....
}
```

EDIT-1:

Try the following approach, using a `Coordinator` class for the `PDFViewDelegate` and getting notified when a `.PDFViewPageChanged` with a `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(...)`.

You will have to adjust the code for your own purpose.

```
struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    let data: Data
    let pdfView = PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
        pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.maxScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: UIViewType, context _: Context) {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
        
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PDFViewDelegate {
        var parent: PDFKitRepresentedView
        var prevPage = -1
        
        init(_ parent: PDFKitRepresentedView) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pageChangeHandler(_:)), name: .PDFViewPageChanged, object: nil)
        }

        @objc func pageChangeHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
            if let thePage = parent.pdfView.currentPage,
                let ndx = parent.pdfView.document?.index(for: thePage), 
                prevPage != ndx {
                print("--------> currentPageIndex: \(ndx) ")
                prevPage = ndx
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT-2:

To access the `currentPage` in `ContentView`, that is, outside the `PDFViewer`,
you can use the following approach.
It uses a `.onReceive(...)` of a page change notification, and some minor changes of
the original code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentPage = 0 

    let pdfViewer: PDFViewer // <--- here
    
    init() {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "pdf"),
        let docData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            self.pdfViewer = PDFViewer(data: docData)
       } else {
            self.pdfViewer = PDFViewer(data: Data())
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("page \(currentPage)")
            pdfViewer
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .PDFViewPageChanged)) { _ in
                    if let thePage = pdfViewer.pdfView.currentPage,
                       let ndx = pdfViewer.pdfView.document?.index(for: thePage), currentPage != ndx {
                        currentPage = ndx
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct PDFViewer: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    let data: Data
    
    let pdfView = PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
        pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.maxScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        pdfView.autoScales = true

        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: UIViewType, context _: Context) {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
    }
}
```

Comment: It only prints on the first run "currentPageIndex:0" on swiping pages it's doing nothing

Comment: show  a minimal code that reproduces your issue:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  you show no code of swiping.

Comment: I have added the code of how I used the "PDFKitRepresentedView" in "ContentView" , the swiping functionality is available by default in "PDFKit" library

Comment: updated my answer (EDIT-1) with code that shows how to get the current page number in a PDFView. Works well for me.

Comment: how can I pass the var "prevPage" to SwiftUI view ?? I tried it with Binding as well as Published   but I am failed to do this

Comment: updated my answer with a way to access the `currentPage` outside the `PDFKitRepresentedView`, renamed `PDFViewer` in the code. Works well for me.